# Whmcs call a php script in a tpl file using smarty variables

Tags: php, templates, whmcs

I have a php script that select from the database and display every row.

I want to display that information in homepage.tpl all that is happening in WHMCS.

I am assuming there is an index file that is already doing that but I have an encrypted version. Wondering whether I can have another php file that will assign my smarty variables and be able to use them in my homepage.tpl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHMCS encourages not to include php code in the tpl files, and recommends adding any php related code to hooks.

For your question:

1 - Add file includes/hooks/my_list.php, and add the following code to it:

```
<?php

if (!defined("WHMCS"))
    die("This file cannot be accessed directly");

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

add_hook('ClientAreaPage', 1, function ($vars) 
{
    //Make sure code executed only in homepage.tpl (index.php)
    if (strpos($vars['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'index.php') !== false) {
        //Read products
        $products = Capsule::table('tblproducts')
                    ->where('hidden', '0')
                    ->orderBy('gid', 'name')
                    ->get();

        //pass variables to the template
        $extra = array("products" => $products, "prdouctsLabel" => "Our Products");

        return $extra;
    }


});
```

2 - In homepage.tpl, access the passed variables as following:

```
<h4>{$prdouctsLabel}</h4>
<ul>
    {foreach item=product from=$products }
    <li>{$product->name}</li>
    {/foreach}

</ul>
```

References:

[WHMCS Hooks](http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks)

[Interacting With The Database](http://docs.whmcs.com/Interacting_With_The_Database)

Comment: Thanks for the solution wesamly it works perfect... now my problem is when i select from a different data base im using a postgress database. heres my code

Comment: '<?php

if (!defined("WHMCS"))
die("This file cannot be accessed directly");
require("new.php");
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

add_hook('ClientAreaPage', 1, function ($vars) 
{
//Make sure code executed only in homepage.tpl (index.php)
 if (strpos($vars['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'index.php') !== false) {

$extra = array("products" => $car, "prdouctsLabel" => "Our Products");

return $extra;
}

});'

Answer (score 0):

dont think you can view that code heres abetter version
 '

```
      if (!defined("WHMCS"))
      die("This file cannot be accessed directly");
      require("new.php");
      use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

      add_hook('ClientAreaPage', 1, function ($vars) 
      {
        //Make sure code executed only in homepage.tpl (index.php)
        if (strpos($vars['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'index.php') !== false) {

        $extra = array("products" => $car, "prdouctsLabel" => "Our Products");

return $extra;
}

 });'
```

Comment: in the code i require new.php which selects from my postgress database and i call the array $car which stores all my values but it doesnt work

Comment: if the $car variable is set in new.php, move the require("new.php"); inside the hook function above if (strpos($vars